# Как лучше нарисовать обрезанный круг?

Tags: android

Как лучше нарисовать обрезанный круг? 
При помощи shape?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Способов миллион и маленькая тележка:

1. [тынц](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=arc+android&type=)
2. Можно нарисовать при помощи `Canvas`